# Putting common functionality in a Flask subclass

Tags: python, flask

I have a website with several Flask apps which all share common some common attributes, so I created the following class:

```
import flask

class MyFlaskApp(flask.Flask):
    def__init__(self, import_name):
        super(MyFlaskApp, self).__init__(import_name)
        # Set up some logging and template paths.

    @self.errorhandler(404)
    def my_404(self, error):
        return flask.render_template("404.html"), 404

    @self.before_request
    def my_preprocessing(self):
        # Do stuff to flask.request
```

Then any other flask apps I have can use it as follows:

```
from myflaskapp import MyFlaskApp

app = MyFlaskApp(__name__)

@app.route("/my/path/")
def my_path():
    return "I'm a pirate, prepare to die!"
```

However it seems that I can't use those decorators like that in the context of a class definition. How else can I achieve this?

Comment: No, you cannot use decorators that refer to `self` because there cannot *be* an instance yet at the time you define the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move your registrations *into the `__init__` method*; at that moment there is a `self` reference:

```
class MyFlaskApp(flask.Flask):
    def__init__(self, import_name):
        super(MyFlaskApp, self).__init__(import_name)
        # Set up some logging and template paths.
        self.register_error_handler(404, self.my_404)
        self.before_request(self.my_preprocessing)

    def my_404(self, error):
        return flask.render_template("404.html"), 404

    def my_preprocessing(self):
        # Do stuff to flask.request
```

Instead of using the [`@app.errorhandler()` decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) I used the slightly more convenient [`app.register_error_handler()` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.register_error_handler), but you could still use

```
self.errorhandler(404)(self.my_404)
```

if you really wanted to. The registration decorators on the Flask object all just register, they don't alter the decorated function or provide a replacement.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Can all the decorators be used in a similar fashion to how `before_request` is being used here?

Comment: @DanielGibbs: yes, just about all decorators in Flask are used just for registering; they don't return a new, wrapped function.